# error while reading .xlsm file

Tags: java, xlsm

I am trying to read a .xlsm file using POI.
My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;;

public class ReadExcelSheet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
final Workbook wb;
FileInputStream fileIn = new           FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\my\\Desktop\\ExcelPORead\\Purchace.xlsm");

wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn); // Error in this line

}
}
```

and I am getting an error at the line "wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn)", it says to "configure Build Path". 
I am using Eclipse and downloaded poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5.jar and add it to the Build path.
But I am not getting what I need to do to make it working.

Kindly suggest me how to remove this error or If you have any better way to read the .xlsm files in Java.

Thanks for your response.

Regards,
Raman

Comment: my\\Desktop it suppose to be my Desktop, or is just to not put your name?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for yur response.
I have tried this and still the same error.
Regards,

Comment: Try this C:\\Users\\my\ Desktop\\ExcelPORead\\Purchace.xlsm

Comment: Thanks,
I tried this.. but still same error..:(